# Send message to specific channel (command on module.exports)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I don't wanna make a mess out of my Main.js so I try to make every possible command through module.exports in other documents.js

Basically I need that if I send a command, the bot will delete my message and post a comment+embed on a specific channel.
This is what I have (making it simple):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'chtest',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        let chComment = 'Normal comment';
            chComment += '\nLine2';
            message.channel.send(chComment)
        const chEmbed = blablaEmbedCode
            message.channel.send(chEmbed)
        message.delete();
    },s
};
```

I've read another Questions and they use

`` client.channels.cache.get(`Channel_ID`).send('Text') ``

I tried using it but I got an error `ReferenceError: client is not defined`

I added **Client** to my **execute** line:
`execute(client, message, args, Discord) {`

And now I have another error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined`

And... I don't know what to do now. Any solutions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using the `Message` class' `client` property. Here are the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) for it.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'chtest',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        let channel = message.client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID');
   //channel is now the channel, unless it could not be found.
channel.send('Message');     
/*let chComment = 'Normal comment';
            chComment += '\nLine2';
            message.channel.send(chComment)
        const chEmbed = blablaEmbedCode
            message.channel.send(chEmbed)
        message.delete();*/
    },
};
```

Comment: Ohhh I see, thank you very much!! I tested it, it worked!